# Postman displaying an Error: format not supported by the requested resource

Tags: java, rest, postman

I was trying my first demo program in Restful APIs using JAX-RS.

I'm using Postman as my REST client. I tried this piece of code which should display `hello world` in my REST client. Instead, I got an error as shown below:

`InjectDemo` class:

```
@Path("/injectdemo")
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public class InjectDemo {

    @GET
    @Path("/annotations")
    public String getParametersUsingAnnotation(){
        return "hello world";
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error in my Postman REST client. Note that, I placed the class files in the correct directory only.

[image]

Comment: Can you show which `Headers` are you sending in `postman`?

Comment: maybe sending as json

Comment: are you sending an accept header with the request?

Comment: Just now, I clicked on a new tab in Postman. I tried the same URI in it. It worked! I got the output ! and why is this ? @Ali

Comment: is your postman defaulting the accept header to text/plain?

Answer (score 1):

You should add `Accept=text/plain` and `Content-Type=text/plain` *Headers* in `postman`.

Or you should set the value of those *Headers* in your `@Produces` annotation.

Comment: Just now, I clicked on a new tab in Postman. I tried the same URI in it. It worked! I got the output ! and why is this ?

Comment: Different tabs can have different Headers, probably that new tab didn't have the `Content-Type` header.